# Domain redirect to main domain with language param (301)

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, multiple-domains, multilingual, top-level-domains

The following scenario: I have purchased multiple domains for a project:

- `domain.app`
- `domain.com`
- `domain.de`

Originally it was planned to display a landing page on `domain.app`.

- On `domain.de` the german version of the PWA.
- On `domain.com` the english version of the PWA.

Now it all seems a bit complicated and I would like to use the following structure:

- `domain.app` as the main domain that recognizes the browser language.
- `domain.de` redirected to `domain.app/de/`
- `domain.com` redirected to `domain.app/en/`

Comment: What is your question?  You outlined a scenario you want to implement, but you didn't pose any question about it.

Comment: The Question is: `Is the Domain Structure a good SEO Oriented way?` or `it works but its not recommended to solve it in this way`.